# Rust hmacsha and hmac-sha1 libraries return different result on calculation

Tags: rust, hmacsha1

I tried to use two Rust libraries to compute hmacsha1: [hmacsha](https://crates.io/crates/hmac-sha) and [hmac-sha1](https://crates.io/crates/hmac-sha1).
This functions use different set of params(**hmacsha** require strings, **hmac-sha1** require `[u8]`) and return different result. I used [this online tool](https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output) to compare. **hmacsha** return same with online tool result, **hmac-sha1** different from both online tool and **hmacsha**.

This is how I use **hmacsha**:

```
const ENCRYPT_KEY: &str = "C2B3723CC6AED9B5343C53EE2F4367CE";
let key = [200, 7, 216, 173, 213, 146, 229, 69, 96, 121, 68, 66, 55, 215, 179, 150, 34, 206, 128, 136, 252, 37, 173, 113, 170, 80, 148, 36, 5, 129, 212, 183, 47, 24, 47, 123, 157, 47, 26, 2];
let hash_key = HmacSha::from(
    &encode_hex(&key), // C807D8ADD592E5456079444237D7B39622CE8088FC25AD71AA5094240581D4B72F182F7B9D2F1A02
    ENCRYPT_KEY,
    Sha1::default()
).compute_digest();

println!("{:?}", encode_hex(&hash_key)); // 545E5C8D754F21DD586BA7378F8AA7AA815F4500
```

This is my encode_hex function I use for both examples:

```
pub fn encode_hex(bytes: &[u8]) -> String {
    let mut s = String::with_capacity(bytes.len() * 2);
    for &b in bytes {
       write!(&mut s, "{:02x}", b).unwrap();
    }
   s.to_uppercase()
}
```

This is how I use **hmac-sha1**:

```
const ENCRYPT_KEY: [u8; 16] = [
    0xC2, 0xB3, 0x72, 0x3C, 0xC6, 0xAE, 0xD9, 0xB5, 0x34, 0x3C, 0x53, 0xEE, 0x2F, 0x43, 0x67, 0xCE
];
let key = [200, 7, 216, 173, 213, 146, 229, 69, 96, 121, 68, 66, 55, 215, 179, 150, 34, 206, 128, 136, 252, 37, 173, 113, 170, 80, 148, 36, 5, 129, 212, 183, 47, 24, 47, 123, 157, 47, 26, 2];
let hash_key = &hmac_sha1(&key, &ENCRYPT_KEY2);

println!("{:?}", encode_hex(&hash_key)); // 80FEC15187802FFB4EA8124220A19DD575E45DC3
```

Could somebody explain what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try passing the raw bytes into `HmacSha::new()`. `HmacSha::from` does not expect a hex encoded string from what I can see. https://docs.rs/hmac-sha/0.6.1/src/hmacsha/lib.rs.html#23-39

Comment: @Dogbert could you clarify what do you mean by "raw" bytes here ? `HmacSha::from` expect string, I pass string into it.

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo hmacsha does expect (or really can take) a string but it uses that string as-is simply converted to binary (using `str::as_bytes`). It does not assume that string is any sort of binary encoding. By passing a hex string to one function and binary data to the other, you're asking for completely different behaviours, as HmacSha will get the key `[0x42, 0x32, 0x42, 0x33, ...`. hmacsha will also work just fine with binary data, pass the same binary data to both an dit should work.

Comment: Can you try `HmacSha::new(&key, ENCRYPT_KEY, Sha1::default())`?

Comment: @Dogbert now it return same result, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HmacSha::from` from `hmac-sha` crate takes a string as the key but it does not expect a hex-encoded string. It instead uses the bytes of the string as-is. This seems like a mistake in the API since this will only accept keys that are valid UTF-8 bytes. You should instead use `HmacSha::new` from the same crate, which accepts a byte slice as the key:

```rust
let hash_key = HmacSha::new(
    &key, // no encode_hex() here
    ENCRYPT_KEY,
    Sha1::default()
).compute_digest();
```